# The House has passed the Big Cat Public Safety Act

Tags: united-states, senate, house-of-representatives, legislative-process, legislation

What happens now? When will the Senate vote on it? And if the Senate passes, what happens then?

Comment: Please be more specific about the type of happenings you're asking about here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On December 6, 2022, the Senate, by voice vote, passed the Big Cat Public Safety Act. The bill will now be sent to the President.

---

For the 117th Congress, the House passed [H.R.263](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/263) - Big Cat Public Safety Act. All Democrats and one-third of Republicans voted for the bill. In committee, Republicans [objected to](https://www.congress.gov/117/crpt/hrpt428/CRPT-117hrpt428.pdf#page=32) "a duplicative regulatory system" involving the Departments of Interior and Agriculture. [govtrack.us](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/117/hr263) currently reports a "17% chance of being enacted according to Skopos Labs".

---

The *Big Cat Public Safety Act* ([H.R.1380](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/1380) 116th Congress) will have no further action because all necessary actions were not complete before the end of the 116th Congress.

A companion bill *Big Cat Public Safety Act* ([S.2561](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/senate-bill/2561) 116th Congress) never got a hearing.

That they cannot become law is true, as well, for measures introduced in the 115th Congress [S.2990](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/senate-bill/2990) and [H.R.1818](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/1818) under the same name.

And similar bills introduced in the 114th, 113th, 112th, etc. Congresses.

Comment: What does that mean then? Does it need to start over again for the 117th Congress?

Comment: It means that it would have to pass the House of Representatives again, as well as the Senate within the same two-year Congress, before becoming law.

Comment: @code_life - Yes, I added additional references for attempts to pass legislation in earlier Congresses.

Comment: @JoeC what about the president? doesn't he need to sign the bill as well?

Comment: @code_life Yes, though with the 10-days exception and veto override there's a sense in which no he doesn't.  But the focus here is on the Congressional side of things.